# Equation with sin 1/x

Tags: trigonometry

I have this equation:

```
x * sin (1/x) = (sin (1/x)) / (1/x)
```

From where did this come from? If we divide both of the parts with 1/x, we should get this:

```
x * sin (1/x) = x*x * ((sin (1/x)) / (1/x))
```

Comment: Laws of fractions: $$a=\frac{1}{1/a}$$

Answer (score 2):

I think you are asking why $x\sin(\frac{1}{x})=\frac{\sin(\frac{1}{x})}{\frac{1}{x}}$. This can be seen by noting that:

$\frac{\sin(\frac{1}{x})}{\frac{1}{x}}=\frac{x}{x}\frac{\sin(\frac{1}{x})}{\frac{1}{x}}=\frac{x\sin(\frac{1}{x})}{x\frac{1}{x}}=x\sin(\frac{1}{x})$

provided $x\neq0$.